# Stored Procedure: Keep Query Result (as Table) in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm from Entity Framework background and I don't do much pure SQL development.

However, when dealing with EF we can do:

```
var persons = from x in db.Person
              where x.Name.Equals("Something")
              select x;
```

or

```
IQuerable<Person> persons = from x in db.Person
                             where x.Name.Equals("Something")
                             select x;
```

But when dealing with stored procedures, how could this be done exactly, like for example I can capture a variable by declaring `DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(15)`, but how to get the returned table result?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `iqueryable` defines a query rather than a result. Execution is deferred. A view might be the closest equivalent though that can't be assigned to a variable.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Doing so because I wanna log activity on a table. For instance I have a login table which has a password field that is scrambled. If a use is trying to login using invalid user and pass, I wanna log the actual input pass, else if the credentials are valid, I will record the scrambled pass. So I wanna make a query first, check if it returned something, do my logging and RETURN the result.

Comment: So this is an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) then. You should ask how to achieve your actual goal not how to achieve the "solution" you have come up with with not much SQL development to base it on.

Answer (score 2):

Create a table variable and insert your data into that:

```
DECLARE @Person table(
    FirstName nvarchar(15),
    LastName nvarchar(15)
);

Insert Into @Person(FirstName, LastName)
Select Firstname, LastName
  From Person
  Where LastName = @LastName; -- where @lastname comes from a sp parameter.
```

Now do stuff like

```
Select count(*) from @Person;
```

Answer (score 0):

simply declare a table variable:

```
DECLARE @TableVariable TABLE 
(
    PrimaryKey INT, 
    Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

and insert the results into this table.

Answer (score 0):

One way as answered by @ps2goat. And if you want Stored Procedure output into table then you can do like this :-

```
DECLARE @Person table
(
    Id        Int Identity(1,1)
   ,FirstName nvarchar(15)
   ,LastName  nvarchar(15)
);

Insert Into @Person(FirstName,LastName)
Exec dbo.USP_SomeStoredProcedure <sp's parameters>;

Select Top 1
        FirstName
       ,LastName
From   @Person As p
Order By p.Id Asc
```

**Note:-** your calling procedure output and table column exactly match should be same

Answer (score -2):

Well I found the right answer myself. I think I have to use cursors and that is the best to do so.

Comment: nooooo, never use cursors for anything that can be done as a set-based operation.  They're extremely slow (comparatively speaking).  If the table variable doesn't fit your needs, you need to update your question to more clearly state what you are trying to do, even if you think cursors are the best fit.  We don't want noobs thinking that cursors are the best option for what you described.

Comment: @ps2goat In my point of view, if you write the same code twice, you are making a mistake. There should never be code duplication, maybe I think so because I'm an OOP guy, but re-writing the table (even for modelling it) does not sound right to me. If I could reuse the table I already got, that would be another story.

Comment: @Arrrr if you find yourself using cursors then it is 99% probable you are making a mistake. SQL is set based and performs much better with set based logic.

Comment: @Arrrr, cursors can be useful, but the case you outlined in your question is not one of them.  That's why it would be better if you could more clearly define the question so that others can see why you think a cursor is better than a set based operation.  We may also be able to show you a better way if cursors are not the best approach for your *actual* problem.

Comment: @MartinSmith: If you read my comment, you see that cursors may not be that bad, but if you have a better solution please share with me.

Comment: @ps2goat: I don't do much pure SQL, but I'm not comfortable defining the same schema again and again. In my opinion this is not right, if I could re-use the schema that has been already defined, I'd definitely go with that solution. Cursors allow me not to so, or not that much at least. I can fetch the first row and ignore the rest. So I don't think any performance issue would exceed a couple of milliseconds.

Comment: All you want is the first row?  Declare parameters and set the row data to those.  Still a lot faster than cursor allocation and deallocation.

Comment: I agreed with @ps2goat, as "@" table variable stored inside the Ram. Cursor loop through the row by row. And if i want first or say last row, then simply add RowNum by using Row_Number() function or take column " Id Identity(1,1)" and then take Select Top 1 FirstName, LastName .... order by Id Asc. its too faster than declaring the cursor.